# Putting text file into 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to store a text file that looks like this below into a 2D Array.

```
24
7
1 6
7 15
13 17
9 23
10 21
13 19
```

And this is my code I have to store it. There are no Syntax errors but I just can't seem to get it to store into my Array. I just need to figure out how to simply store this into my array.

```
        FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));
        Scanner src = new Scanner(input);
        ArrayList<Integer> lines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        src.useDelimiter(" ");

        while(src.hasNextInt()) {
            lines.add(src.nextInt());
        }
        int[][] fileArray = new int[lines.size()][];
        lines.toArray(fileArray);
```

-Thanks Mike

Comment: how about a change of logic.  Read each line as a String, split using `" "` convert values to ints and add to array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
    FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));
    Scanner src = new Scanner(input);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> board = new ArrayList<>();

    while(src.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] line = src.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        board.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for(String num : line)
        {
            if(num.matches("\\d+"))
                board.get(board.size() - 1).add(Integer.parseInt(num));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < board.get(i).size(); j++)
            System.out.print(board.get(i).get(j) + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped so much the only thing I had to modify was the \\d to \\d+ due for the numbers that used more than one digit

Comment: a lot nicer logic